# android.util.Base64 for JSE 7

Tags: java

If you want to make Android's `android.util.Base64` available in Java environments,
what package do you add? It's better if I can get a maven dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/index.html), it contains a class `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.

Java 8 is going to have a class [`java.util.Base64`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), but it's not released yet (and you cannot use it on Java 7).